# неправильная кодировка в ssis

Tags: mysql, sql-server, csv, integration-services, ssis

Доброго времени суток !

Создал интеграционный пакет, который берет данные из таблицы в mssql, и далее параллельно записывает их в файл .csv и таблицу в mysql.

Данные есть как на латинице, так и на кириллице, при этом в файл .csv они записываются корректно, а вот в mysql знаки кириллицы записываются как знаки вопроса (?).

Помогите советом, как решить проблему, спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Никто не сталкивался ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем проблема решилась при замене OLE DB подключения на ADO NET.